# return a value from .bat file to the calling application

Tags: java, batch-file

I am using the below code to execute the .bat file and read the response.

```
java.lang.ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C", "C:\\main.bat");
    java.lang.Process p = pb.start();            
    String line;
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line); <--this works
    }
    r.close();
}
}
```

The main.bat will just echo the value

```
call sample.bat c:\sample.txt value1
echo %value1% <---this works
```

However now I want to pass a parameter from the java code that will be set in the batch file and can be printed in the java code.

```
java.lang.ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C", "C:\\main.bat" +s1);
java.lang.Process p = pb.start(); 
System.out.println(s1); <--- this does not work
```

Can someone please let me know how to return a value from .bat file to any calling application?

Answer (score 3):

**Please Try Following Code**


**Step 1 : Create new Class CommandStreamReader**

```
        import java.io.BufferedReader;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.InputStream;
        import java.io.InputStreamReader;
        class CommandStreamReader extends Thread
        {
            InputStream is;
            String type;

            CommandStreamReader(InputStream is, String type)
            {
                this.is = is;
                this.type = type;
            }

            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                    String line=null;
                    while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
                        System.out.println(type + ">" + line);    
                    } catch (IOException ioe)
                      {
                        ioe.printStackTrace();  
                      }
            }
        }
```

**Step 2 : Create main.bat File on C dirctory with your Content,Here For Example**

echo santosh shinde

**Step 3 : Create New class CmdTest**

```
        public class CmdTest { 
            public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            try{
                        String[] cmd = new String[3];
                        cmd[0] = "cmd.exe" ;
                        cmd[1] = "/C" ;
                        cmd[2] = "C:/main.bat";
                        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
                        System.out.println("Execing " + cmd[0] + " " + cmd[1]  + " " + cmd[2]);
                        Process proc = rt.exec(cmd);
                        // any error message?
                        CommandStreamReader errorStream = new CommandStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream(), "ERROR");            

                        // any output? Here We take return or output value from bach file
                        CommandStreamReader outputStream = new CommandStreamReader(proc.getInputStream(), "OUTPUT");

                        // kick them off
                        errorStream.start();
                        outputStream.start();

                        // any error???
                        int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
                        System.out.println("ExitValue: " + exitVal);   

                    } catch(Throwable t){
                        t.printStackTrace();
                }  
            }

            }
        }
```

**Step 4 : Output**

```
  Execing cmd.exe /C F:/main.bat
  OUTPUT>
  OUTPUT>C:\Users\Admin\workspace\BuilAPKAnt>echo santosh 
  OUTPUT>santosh shinde
  ExitValue: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
exit /B 42 , there is a great batch file resource in http://ss64.com/nt/
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of appending s1 to the last argument, pass it as a fourth argument. That should work.

Comment: doesnt work
    String s1 ="";java.lang.ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C", "C:\\folderdir\\code  \\callCommon.bat", "s1");

Comment: sysout(s1) doesn't print the value that I set in the the batch file

Comment: Now I actually understand the question. There is no way for a batch file to set a variable in java code. By the way, it's not a very good idea to call a batch file in java code. It thereafter only works on Windows, which many people don't have. Just implement the batch file in java, and call commands if nessecary using `ProcessBuilder` or `Runtime.exec()`.

Comment: the java code is able to read the value from the batch file when I just echo the value. 
But I am not sure which other applications or tools will be used to execute the batch file. 
So I wanted to make sure that this way of returning the value back to the calling application works for all the applications.

Comment: echoing the value is actually the only possible way to return any information from a batch file, short of exiting with a specific exit code, which isn't very elegant and can only return an int.

Comment: tbodt - I agree with you. java code is able to capture the echoed value. will it also work with other applications that execute the batch file ex - tivoli workload scheduler

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just using your variable as parameter, instead of concatenating it to the main.bat call?

```
java.lang.ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C", "C:\\main.bat", s1);
```

Then in your batch file, something like:

```
echo %1
```

Comment: I tried setting it as a 4th parameter instead of concatenating it. I am also setting set 
    %~1=%value1% 
in the batch file. However I am still not getting the response in the java code when I print s1.
Do I need to change something in  the batch file?

Comment: Not sure... You should probably post your batch file in your question.

Answer (score 0):

As Mena has suggested, using your variable as a parameter and then using `%1` works fine
note: you cannot pass more than 9 parameters in this fasion `%1 - %9`

to then retrieve the a variable from the batch file to Java i believe you can use `%ERRORVALUE%`
as an exit code

**EDIT**

this is a bit round about, but you could also separate the Java so that after passing the parameter
the batch file uses it then calls up a separate java passing the variable you wish to use.